# Removing parts of a content type

Tags: theming

so, I was trying to get rid of the comment title and there is a lot to read about that on the net, but I still had my issues getting it right, so I came up with this, but I believe there should be a better way.
What is the best way of doing this:

```
function theme_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
// Remove the comment title
  $vars['title'] = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your content type to not use comment title by unchecking "Allow comment title" under the settings for your content type.

[image: disable comment title]

Then I would copy comment.tpl.php to your theme and customize the output there instead of just unsetting the title value in theme_preprocess_comment().

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this by custom coding. Then create a custom Module. The following code will do this.

function your_modulename_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
 //This disables title field.

$form['subject']['#access'] = FALSE;
 return $form;

}

Hope this helps you.